# Composer: How to specified branch until commit number?

Tags: composer-php

I would like to ask you how to specify in composer.json package with given branch and until given commit.

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.3.0-dev#98f6969e9c2ebbb00d81bf9362f072cb200da38a",
```

I would like to get branch 2.3 from symfony including that commit. But nothing after it. Btw., I don't want to download tagged branch v2.3.0.

Composer doesn't accept the settings above.

Really thanks.
Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why one would do this. As this is a very rare usecase, I'd think the only option you have is to fake a composer.lock file that points to that commit.

The better way seems to accept the updates in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Specific branches and commits can be used like this:

```
"symfony/symfony": "dev-2.3#98f6969e9c2ebbb00d81bf9362f072cb200da38a",
```